# Bash redirection weird behavior

Tags: bash, io-redirection, trap

I was messing around with trapping exit codes and redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` of a case statement when I ran into an interesting outcome that I am hoping someone can shine some light into.

I am using bash 5.1.16.

This block can be used to replicate the behavior I am seeing:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cleanup () {
    case $? in
        1) echo "message 1" ;;
        9) echo "message 2" ;;
    esac
}

trap cleanup EXIT

case 0 in
    0) exit 1 ;;
    2) echo "yay" ;;
esac > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The xtrace output with `> /dev/null 2>&1`:

```
+ trap cleanup EXIT
```

The xtrace output without `> /dev/null 2>&1`:

```
+ trap cleanup EXIT
+ case 0 in
+ exit 1
+ cleanup
+ case $? in
+ echo 'message 1'
message 1
```

What's going on here? How is the redirection causing that the case statement isn't executed at all?

Comment: how do you run the script if you can see the xtrace output even with stderr redirected to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `EXIT` trap is executed with the redirections that are in place when the trap is called.  In your code, calling `exit 1` in the main `case` statement causes the `cleanup` function to inherit the redirections from that statement.

A shorter example which does not print anything to standard output:

```bash
cleanup () {
        echo bye
}

trap cleanup EXIT

exit >/dev/null
```

Remove `>/dev/null` to have the script output `bye`.

The tracing output produced by `set -x` is written to the standard error stream and your code is redirecting this stream to `/dev/null` too.  In short, your function's `case` statement *is* executed, but you discard all output from the script so you won't see the output from its `echo`, nor the tracing output.

Also note that some other shells, like `dash` and `ksh`, will not behave in this way.

To work around this in the `bash` shell, you may duplicate the standard error file descriptor at the start of the script and then explicitly use that in your `cleanup` function. I'm using the standard error stream for this as I'm presuming it will be used for *diagnostic* messages.

Your code with my additions:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -x

exec {fd}>&2

cleanup () {
    case $? in
        1) echo "message 1" ;;
        9) echo "message 2" ;;
    esac >&$fd
}

trap cleanup EXIT

case 0 in
    0) exit 1 ;;
    2) echo "yay" ;;
esac > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The descriptor allocated by the shell and assigned to `fd` will be 10 or higher.

Since `sh` is not always `bash`, I have also changed the `#!`-line to explicitly call the `bash` executable.

Running this:

```bash
$ ./script
+ exec
+ trap cleanup EXIT
message 1
```

Comment: That's really interesting actually that the redirection is inherited, but to some extent makes sense why it would, just defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve where the case statement produces no output and any exits are dealt with by the trap with a corresponding message to explain why the early exit. Thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyBB See workaround at end.